# DB2 Stored Procedure parameter "is not valid in the context where it is used"

Tags: sql, db2

I am trying to create the following stored procedure:

```
-- <ScriptOptions statementSeparator="@"/>
-- <ScriptOptions errors="off" platform390="off"/>
@
DROP SPECIFIC PROCEDURE DEPCLH.GetTransactionSummaryByDateRange@

CREATE PROCEDURE  DEPCLH.GetTransactionSummaryByDateRange (in p_DCHDSB_ID INTEGER,in p_StartDate varchar(50),in p_EndDate varchar(50)) 
SPECIFIC  DEPCLH.GetTransactionSummaryByDateRange
LANGUAGE SQL
RESULT SET 1@

BEGIN

DECLARE C_OUTPUT CURSOR WITH RETURN FOR
SELECT
sub.DCHDSB_ID AS FACILITYID,
sub.DCHDSB_CODE AS FACILITYCODE,
sub.NAME AS FACILITYNAME,
SUM(dep.AMOUNT) "TOTALAMOUNT",
COUNT(*) "TRANSACTIONCOUNT"
FROM DEPCLH.DEPOSIT_SUBSCRIBER sub
INNER JOIN DEPCLH.DEPOSIT dep ON dep.DCHDSB_ID=sub.DCHDSB_ID
WHERE sub.DCHDSB_ID=p_DCHDSB_ID AND dep.CREATED_TS BETWEEN p_StartDate AND p_EndDate
GROUP BY sub.DCHDSB_ID,sub.DCHDSB_CODE,sub.NAME
FOR READ ONLY;

OPEN C_OUTPUT;

END 
@

GRANT EXECUTE ON SPECIFIC PROCEDURE  DEPCLH.GetTransactionSummaryByDateRange TO PUBLIC
@

COMMIT
@
```

I receive the following error:

> DB21034E  The command was processed as an SQL statement because it was
>   not a  valid Command Line Processor command.  During SQL processing it
>   returned: SQL0206N  "P_DCHDSB_ID" is not valid in the context where it
>   is used.  LINE  NUMBER=3.  SQLSTATE=42703

Comment: I think the problem is that you have a statement terminator character @ in the middle of the `CREATE PROCEDURE` statement: `LANGUAGE SQL
RESULT SET 1@

BEGIN`

Comment: @mustaccio that was the problem. Thank you. Solution posted above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typo found in code. Thank you for the good eye!

```
-- <ScriptOptions statementSeparator="@"/>
    -- <ScriptOptions errors="off" platform390="off"/>
    @
    DROP SPECIFIC PROCEDURE DEPCLH.GetTransactionSummaryByDateRange@

    CREATE PROCEDURE  DEPCLH.GetTransactionSummaryByDateRange (in p_DCHDSB_ID INTEGER,in p_StartDate varchar(50),in p_EndDate varchar(50)) 
    SPECIFIC  DEPCLH.GetTransactionSummaryByDateRange
    LANGUAGE SQL
    RESULT SET 1

    BEGIN

    DECLARE C_OUTPUT CURSOR WITH RETURN FOR
    SELECT
    sub.DCHDSB_ID AS FACILITYID,
    sub.DCHDSB_CODE AS FACILITYCODE,
    sub.NAME AS FACILITYNAME,
    SUM(dep.AMOUNT) "TOTALAMOUNT",
    COUNT(*) "TRANSACTIONCOUNT"
    FROM DEPCLH.DEPOSIT_SUBSCRIBER sub
    INNER JOIN DEPCLH.DEPOSIT dep ON dep.DCHDSB_ID=sub.DCHDSB_ID
    WHERE sub.DCHDSB_ID=p_DCHDSB_ID AND dep.CREATED_TS BETWEEN p_StartDate AND p_EndDate
    GROUP BY sub.DCHDSB_ID,sub.DCHDSB_CODE,sub.NAME
    FOR READ ONLY;

    OPEN C_OUTPUT;

    END 
    @

    GRANT EXECUTE ON SPECIFIC PROCEDURE  DEPCLH.GetTransactionSummaryByDateRange TO PUBLIC
    @

    COMMIT
    @
```